# How to write array instead of using if then statement

Tags: arrays, if-statement, sas

I want to create a new numeric variable to set the character to a specific sequence. I want to do it by writing an array not if then.

Here is my data and code.

```
char  num
OR     1
SU     2
DI     3
DK     4
HJ     5
SYS    6
```

my original code to create num is :

```
data v;
set v;
if char='OR' then num=1;
if char='SU' then num=2;
if char='DI' then num=3;
if char='DK' then num=4;
if char='HJ'    then num=5;
if char='SYS'   then num=6;
run;
```

I want to do it in array.Thanks.

Comment: "_I want to do it in array._" Have you tried yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what formats/informats are for...

```
proc format ;
  invalue NUM
    'OR'  = 1
    'SU'  = 2
    'DI'  = 3
    'DK'  = 4
    'HJ'  = 5
    'SYS' = 6
    ;
run ;

data want ;
  set have ;
  num = input(char,NUM.) ;
run ;
```